# Connect two local networks

Tags: router, wifi, local-area-network, netgear, 10gbethernet

I'm trying to connect two local networks together.

**Network 1** (192.168.1.1) is connected to 10GBe Internet via router with dhcp. I've added switch Netgear XS708T for more 10G ports (Clients 1 and 2).

Via this switch I've connected a wifi router with DHCP (network 2).

**Network 2** (192.168.2.1) is for wifi devices only (Client A, B etc.)

**Question 1:** Is it possible / How to configure XS708T to connect both networks so Client 1 or Client 2 would see Client A or any client from network 2?

**Question 2:** Do I need any other device to make it happen?

Thanks
Tom from [Serwer.io](https://serwer.io/en/)

Comment: If you disable the DHCP server on the Wifi Access Point and connect it to network `192.168.1.0/24` through a **LAN** port, you'll end up with only one easy to administer `192.168.1.0/24`. Usually those ports are bridged with the WiFi.

Comment: I had this previously. But looking forward to creating config from my 2 networks scenario image. Do you reckon it's possible with my equipment?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should disable NAT on you Wifi Access Point. I am not sure if this is possible with NetGear's stock firmware.

Second: clients 1 and 2 don't know the route to the `192.168.2.0/24` network, so they send everything to their default gateway (`192.168.1.1`). If you add a static route to `192.168.2.0/24` on the modem, everything should work.

**Remark:** Clients A and B don't know the route to `192.168.1.0/24` either, but their default gateway (the WiFi AP) does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the reason users inside Network 2 can see the Network 1, but not the other way around is because most SMB routers implement something called NAT (Network Address Translation). Long story made short: NAT is a technology that translates internal addresses - something like 192.168.0.0/24 - to Internet valid ones, like 187.200.145.24/32, and vice-versa, and was a response to the Internet address shortage. One of its aspects is that it also acts like a firewall, so computers from the Network 1 cannot access directly the ones inside Network 2.

So you have two options to solve your problem:

- Buy a piece of equipment that supports routing without NAT, like a MikroTik router or;
- Instead of connecting the two networks using a router and the WAN port, why don't you create a single network, like 192.168.0.0/24, connecting a XS708T port to one of the wireless access point LAN ports, and disable DHCP in it?

Hope that helps.